# How do you clear the snippet Metadata / Open Graph cache of an URL on Whatsapp?

Tags: caching, whatsapp, meta-tags, share-open-graph

I created a new website using wordpress, but I shared the link on whatsapp before I set it up entirely. The snippet shown on whatsapp included the theme's name and author's information in the meta description.

I updated the meta data and opengraph information on the web page. Despite this, when I share a link on whatsapp, the preview shown contains the older meta description information which I suppose is cached by Whatsapp at their side.

How do I force-clear this cache? Alternatively how often does Whatsapp refresh the cache?

Using a new or slightly different URL does show an updated snippet, however this does not resolve my issue as the incorrectly cached URL is the root URL.

Answer (score 1):

Clean whatsapp cache for me it works. for android:
Go to Settings on your Android phone and click the “Apps” option.
Scroll down until you see WhatsApp, then tap it.
Tap Storage (or Memory), which will bring up a list of storage options for your app.  – You can choose between Clear Cache or Clear Data (which clears both cache and data).
Pick whichever one is in need of clearing if applicable to how you’re using the app.
Iphone:
Go to the “Settings” menu on your iPhone and select “General”.
Scroll down and tap on “Data and Storage Usage.
Tap on “Manage Storage”, and then select “WhatsApp” messenger.
Now you will see how much storage is being used by the app; hit “Clear Cache” when it’s full or if you want to remove some data stored in there but keep your chats intact.